# Get currently connected systems in a domain using c#

Tags: c#, networking, windows-server-2012

Hi Everyone!
      I want the details of currently online systems in a network using c#. Our machines connected through Windows Server 2012. How to achieve this goal ? someone guide if I wrong? This program going to run on Server machine.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use Active Directory (LDAP) and query all pcs which are in the domain. To check if they are online you got to ping each PC (maybe with multiple threads).

EDIT:

You can create a script which logs the logins/logoffs of the users. The program just would have to go though the list check who is currently online. And afterwards you can get more computer information with [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/01eaf9dd-ac07-45bc-8d01-9fc85ba9db9f/find-computer-name-user-is-logged-onto?forum=winserverDS):

Create a Share on a Server and give right NTFS and Share permissions
Create a Batch file in which you put this script:

`echo user: %username%  computer: %computername% date: %date% > \\Server\Share\info.txt`

Use group policies to apply this Batch file as a logon script

At the end you will get in the text file info.txt:

- The user name
- The used computer
- The date of logon

Comment: I'm getting all systems. I want only the online systems. pinging all the is consumes lot of time. I want those details at every 2 mins.